# How can I switch the currency of a user in spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

In my spree store I have changed the currency settings from USD to AUD and this seems to work mostly but for the existing users when and item is added to the cart the cart shows the old USD price despite showing the new AUD price before adding to cart.

Inspecting the order in the rails console shows the order is set to USD still, new users have their orders set to AUD. How can I change it so all users are now on the new currency?

Comment: How did you make this change? did you run rake db:seed after changing in spree initializer?

Comment: Changed it in the admin page by switching the setting in general settings. I did not run db:seed again.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised that there is a field in the user profile that stores his/her preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order.rb there is a before_validation

`before_validation :set_currency`

and code for this method is

```
def set_currency
  self.currency = Spree::Config[:currency] if self[:currency].nil?
end
```

here currency is set to default currency only if it's not present, So if you want all the active orders to get modified with the new currency that you set through general settings, you can modify the above method to ensure it always set currency before validation.

```
def set_currency
  self.currency = Spree::Config[:currency]
end
```

Please let me know if you still face any issues